# Should sitemap must have main page url as well?

Tags: sitemap, web.sitemap

I know sitemap should have all urls associated with the site, which eventually helps google to crawl. 
My question is, Is it wise to have main url as well in the sitemap OR it doesnot have any meaning?

Answer (score 0):

Sitemaps do not have a 'main page' concept, so it does not have any meaning.

But, by all means, including the URL to what you consider to be your main page in your sitemap always helps.